# Gamma function properties

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, gamma-function, fractional-calculus

Hello everybody can I ask about this property :

For $z$ small between 0 and 1,
$
{\mathrm{(}}\mathit{\Gamma}{\mathrm{(}}{z}{\mathrm{))}}^{\mathrm{{-}}{1}}\mathrm{\approx}{z}.
$

Is there any explanation .
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$z\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$$
$$z\to 0\quad\implies\quad \Gamma(z+1)\approx \Gamma(1)=1$$
$$ z\Gamma(z)\approx 1$$
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\approx z$$
For more accurate approximates, see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General

Answer (score 0):

$\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$, so for small $x$, $\Gamma(1+x)\approx1-\gamma x$. Thus,
$$
\Gamma(x)=\tfrac{\Gamma(1+x)}x\approx\frac1x-\gamma
$$
where $\gamma=0.5772156649$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(x)}\approx x+\gamma x^2
$$